# Ion RangeSlider not reloading correctly in Angular 9 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, slider

I am trying to integrate [Ion.RangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_interactions.html) into an Angular 9 project to select a range of dates. I'm having an issue where the slider works when it initially loads on a page; however it doesn't load right when I navigate back to the same page.

***(Edited to add routes)***
For example, here is a view when I load a page in my project (`/#/category?id=13&data_list_id=15`), and the slider is loading as expected:
[image: Screenshot of slider working on a page]
The next tab over navigates to (`/#/category?id=13&data_list_id=16`) also generates the slider as expected:
[image: Screenshot of slider working on another page]
Returning to the initial summary view (`/#/category?id=13&data_list_id=15`) results in the slider appearing as an input box and not working properly.
[image: Screenshot of slider failing to load properly when navigating back to initial page]

Below are sections of code from my component that I think are the relevant parts to generating the slider.

***date-slider.component.html***

```
<label [for]="'dateFrom'" class="visuallyhidden">Date From:</label>
<input type="text" [name]="'dateFrom'" [id]="'dateFrom'" [value]="sliderDates[start]" class="date-input js-from" />
<div class="slider-container">
    <input class="sliders" type="text" [id]="'slider'" value="" aria-label="date-range-slider" />
</div>
<label [for]="'dateTo'" class="visuallyhidden">Date To:</label>
<input type="text" [name]="'dateTo'" [id]="'dateTo'" [value]="sliderDates[end]" class="date-input js-to" />
```

***date-slider.component.ts***

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.dates && this.dates.length) {
      const defaultRanges = this.findDefaultRange(this.dates, this.freq, this.defaultRange, this.dateFrom, this.dateTo);
      // Start and end used for 'from' and 'to' inputs in slider
      // If start/end exist in values array, position handles at start/end; otherwise, use default range
      this.start = defaultRanges.start;
      this.end = defaultRanges.end;
      this.sliderDates = defaultRanges.sliderDates; // Array of dates for the slider i.e. ['2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005']
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const $fromInput = $(`#dateFrom`);
    const $toInput = $(`#dateTo`);
    const $range = $(`#slider`).data('ionRangeSlider');
    this.initRangeSlider(this.sliderDates, this.start, this.end, this.freq);
    // Set change functions for 'from' and 'to' date inputs
    this.setInputChangeFunction($fromInput, this.sliderDates, $range, 'from', this.portalSettings, this.freq);
    this.setInputChangeFunction($toInput, this.sliderDates, $range, 'to', this.portalSettings, this.freq);
    this.updateChartsAndTables($fromInput.prop('value'), $toInput.prop('value'), this.freq)
    this.cd.detectChanges(); // cd refers to ChangeDetectorRef
  }

  initRangeSlider(sliderDates: Array<any>, start: number, end: number, freq: string) {
    const updateChartsAndTables = (from, to, freq) => this.updateChartsAndTables(from, to, freq);
    const $fromInput = $(`#dateFrom`);
    const $toInput = $(`#dateTo`);
    $(`#slider`).ionRangeSlider({
      min: 0,
      from: start,
      to: end,
      values: sliderDates,
      prettify_enabled: false,
      hide_min_max: true,
      hide_from_to: true,
      keyboard: true,
      keyboard_step: 1,
      skin: 'round',
      type: 'double',
      onChange: function (data) {
        $fromInput.prop('value', data.from_value);
        $toInput.prop('value', data.to_value);
      },
      onFinish: function (data) {
        updateChartsAndTables(data.from_value, data.to_value, freq);
      }
    });
  }
```

I have tried using the [ng2-ion-range-slider](https://github.com/PhilippStein/ng2-ion-range-slider#readme) wrapper, but I end up with the following error when I load it into my module:

> This likely means that the library (ng2-ion-range-slider) which declares IonRangeSliderModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

(Weirdly the slider works fine on an existing project that is basically the same application. The existing application was developed back when Angular was at version 2. It became a multiple app project where all the components, services, and individual app modules were all in the same `src` folder. But now that Angular-cli supports generating multiple apps in the same project, I'm trying to split things up and keep reusable/common components in their own custom library.)

Comment: If you change routes, but the route you are navigating to specifies the same `component` as the route you are navigating from, the _instance_ will be reused. Therefore lifecycle hooks will not be reinvoked. Not sure if that's the issue because your navigation structure, and what you mean by "page" is not described.

Comment: Yes, sorry for for being unclear about the "pages", the routing is such that the `/#/category?id=13&data_list_id=15` corresponds to the first and third screenshots, and `/#/category?id=13&data_list_id=16` to the second. If it's the case that the lifecycle hooks aren't being reinvoked, then I shouldn't be able to console log anything from inside of `ngAfterViewInit` when I navigate right? I've been able to log from there and `initRangeSlider` when navigating between those routes, so it seems like they're being reinvoked.

Comment: That is odd. [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#!#hooks-overview) is very explicit that `ngAfterViewInit` is called only once. (I did incorrectly because `ngAfterViewChecked` and `ngAfterContentChecked` may be called multiple times).

Comment: Also, this documents the router's reuse: https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse